# Android Internet Connection checker OUTSIDE the app

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

My app needs to do something whenever the internet is connected and vice-versa. However, I need to do this **OUTSIDE** my application. There are a lot of ideas and help here on stackoverflow but it is always **WITHIN** the application. I know that the AlarmManager works outside the application but it would just be draining the battery if I try to check if there's internet connection every 5 minutes. What I wanted is to check the connection outside the app to download something.

I also found out that Intent Service can work outside the application as well. I have tried to put this inside the Wakeful Broadcast Receiver. However, it is still not being called.

Can someone out there help me? Thanks!

Here's my Wakeful Broadcast Receiver

```
public class ConnectivityOutsideAppReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = ConnectivityOutsideAppReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    private static boolean connection = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                ConnectivityOutsideAppService.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is
        // launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)

        ));
    }

}
```

This is the Intent Service

public class ConnectivityOutsideAppService extends IntentService {

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = ConnectivityOutsideAppService.class.getSimpleName();
private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
private static boolean connection = false;
private Context context;

public ConnectivityOutsideAppService() {
   super(ConnectivityOutsideAppService.class.getSimpleName());
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    connectivityManager =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    checkConnectionOnDemand();

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, " ## onHandleIntent##");
    if (connection == true
            && intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,
            false)) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, " ## connection == true ##");
        connection = false;
    } else if (connection == false
            && !intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,
            false)) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, " ## connection == false ##");
        connection = true;
    }

    ConnectivityOutsideAppReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

public static boolean hasConnection() {
    return connection;
}

private void checkConnectionOnDemand() {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, " ## checkConnectionOnDemand ##");
    final NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null || info.getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        if (connection == true) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, " ## connection == true ##");
            connection = false;
        }
    } else {
        if (connection == false) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, " ## connection == false ##");
            connection = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my Android Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <service
        android:name="com.timetrackermobilelog.BusinessServices.ConnectivityOutsideAppService"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.timetrackermobilelog.Utilities.ConnectivityOutsideAppService"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:process=":remote">

        <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="com.timetrackermobilelog.Utilities.ConnectivityOutsideAppService" />
            <category android:name="com.Utilities" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I have tried registering the receiver inside the Activity but it doesn't work as well.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.pointwest.timetrackermobilelog.Utilities.ConnectivityOutsideAppReceiver");
ConnectivityOutsideAppReceiver connectivityOutsideAppReceiver = new ConnectivityOutsideAppReceiver();
registerReceiver(connectivityOutsideAppReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: Register your Receiver in the manifest for the [`CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` action](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges), instead of your custom action.

Comment: have you debug your code..? where should  you get problem..?

Comment: Hi @MikeM. I'll that one out and get back to you.

Comment: @VishalHalani. I already did and there's no error. ConnectivityOutsideAppService isn't called.

Comment: OK. Btw, make sure to remove the `<category>` from the `<intent-filter>`, too.

Comment: @MikeM. It called the ConnectivityOutsideAppService. However it threw an error.  `java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.timetrackermobilelog.BusinessServices.ConnectivityOutsideAppService.onHandleIntent(ConnectivityOutsideAppService.java:30)`. That is this line : `connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`

Comment: The `Context` is null when you assign it to your field in the constructor. Get rid of `context`, and just call `getSystemService()`. There's no point in keeping a `Context` field in a `Service` anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks! It worked! I will write the answer here. Kudos to you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Mike M. in giving the answer with just a few lines of changes.

In Android Manifest, change it to :

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

And onHandleIntent of the Service, change it to :

```
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```